Trouble finding image assets
I am new to Flutter and was having trouble finding / loading my image assets.  I was loading them as follows:
      Image.asset(
        "assets/my_image.png",
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
        package: 'mypackage',
        filterQuality: FilterQuality.high,
      ),

The pubspec.yaml looked fine:
  assets:
    - assets/

I finally figured it out, and the answer was so simple that I wanted to share it to help others who might have the same problem.

The package parameter should only be provided if the image is not in the package or application that you are creating.
I presumed that the parameter was always needed, and it could not find the package which is my own package. This still seems strange to me, as all of the Dart import expressions work perfectly fine when reflecting back to my own package.
The correct solution was simply to remove the package parameter:
      Image.asset(
        "assets/my_image.png",
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
        filterQuality: FilterQuality.high,
      ),

